# Access reference to calling component from hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use React's custom hooks to call my backend and automatically read responses for errors.  I would like to be able to print out the display name of the calling component when errors occur.

```
/********************/
/*    mock server   */
/********************/

function API(endpoint) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                res({ error: "The server encountered an error" });
            } else {
                return res({
                    lastUpdate: { timestamp: 1593466223741 }
                }[endpoint]);
            }
        }, 500);
    });
}



/********************/
/*      client      */
/********************/

function useAPI(endpoint) {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({ loading: true });
    React.useEffect(() => {
        API(endpoint)
            .then(response => {
                const { error } = response;
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`${React.useCaller().displayName} encountered an error while calling the API:\n${error}`);
                    setState({ error, loading: false });
                } else {
                    setState({ data: response, loading: false });
                }
            });
    }, []);

    return state;
}

function App() {
    const { error, loading, data } = useAPI("lastUpdate");

    return <div>{
        loading ?
            "loading..." : (
                error ?
                    error :
                    data.timestamp
            )
    }</div>;
}

const target = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(target);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, target);
```

Here, I've used `React.useCaller()` as a stand-in for what I'd like to do - **getting a reference to the component which called `useAPI`**.  Does React have anything like this?  I'd like to avoid using `Function.caller` as it is deprecated.

Comment: You can get the call stack with `new Error().stack`

Comment: @HMR I'd prefer to not have to parse the stack string